# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in php on line 48

Tags: php, html

afternoon\am having difficulties in determining the error of the code and i would need assistance. each time i execute the code am given an error in which i am unable to determine the error itself

```
<?php 
    include('functions.php');
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- notification message -->
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
            <div class="error success" >
                <h3>
                    <?php 
                        echo $_SESSION['success']; 
                        unset($_SESSION['success']);
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <!-- logged in user information -->
        <div class="profile_info">
            <img src="images/user_profile.png"  >

            <div>
                <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?></strong>

                    <small>
                        <i  style="color: #888;">(<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['user']['user_type']); ?>)</i> 
                        <br>
                        <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a>
                    </small>

                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket in the first lines of your code :

```
<?php 
include('functions.php');
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
} // <- Here is the mistake
?>
```